# display message using JSF

Tags: jsf

I'm completely new in JSF. I'm using this tutorial: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf
According to it I created a first project. Here's the Java code:

```
package com.tutorialspoint.test;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

@ManagedBean(name = "helloWorld", eager = true)
public class HelloWorld {

    public HelloWorld() {
        System.out.println("HelloWorld started!");
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }

}
```

this is home.xhtml file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>JSF Tutorial!</title>
</head>

<body>
#{helloWorld.getMessage()}
</body>
</html>
```

when I enter this address in my browser: http://localhost:8080/helloworld/home.jsf the tab's title "JSF Tutorial!" is displayed but the content (the text "Hello World" not. Could I ask you for some hints what can be missing?
If you need some more information/code from other files, just let me know.
BTW, I'm using Wildfly 10.1.0 as an application server where I deploy the updated .war file.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: it looks like you're missing some elements from the code example, e.g., the `@ManagedProperty(value = "#{message}")` looks important.

Comment: Instead of that tutorial, I would rather go with a fully 2.x focused one like this: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/jsf/916/getting-started-with-jsf/3036/installing-jsf#t=201706200625292197528 By the way, properties are accessed via the getter this way: `#{helloWorld.message}`. Still, you lack some info. Is the managed bean bein created? Do you get the faces servlet (javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet) hit? You need to do some debugging work.

Comment: and what if you replace `#helloWorld.message` with `<h:outputText value="#helloWorld.message"/>`  (add the namespace declaration to) and do a view-source of the page in the browser? What do you see then?

Comment: This tutorial also uses the JSF annotations that are deprecated with JSF 2.3. One more reason to use a ew tutorial

Comment: when I use <h:outputText value="#helloWorld.message"/> I get below error:

Comment: Context Path:
/helloworld

Servlet Path:
/home.jsf

Path Info:
null

Query String:
null

Stack Trace
javax.servlet.ServletException: Error Parsing /home.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 10] The prefix "h" for element "h:outputText" is not bound.
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:671)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest

Comment: (ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

Comment: io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)

Comment: io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)

Comment: io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)

Comment: io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)

Comment: io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)

Comment: io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: (I had to divide it into parts because it was very long)

Comment: finally, @Xtreme Biker, this tutorial stackoverflow.com/documentation/jsf/916/… helped; I've redone my code according to it and it works, thanks for a hint :)

Comment: @rybenka glad it worked. For the next time, better edit your own question adding the stack trace or whatever you want instead of posting it as comments.